# substring of minimal length that is not present in the file

Tags: string, algorithm

I am stuck on this interview question :
**Given a file of N bytes. Find a sub-string of minimal length that is not present in the file.**

Any idea?
thanks.

Comment: can you give an example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suffix Trees Baby!

Create a suffix tree. Find the shallowest null node.

Comment: Yes, that's better than my solution.

Comment: @Ukkonen : Can you explain your solution please?

Answer (score 2):

You can build a suffix array, and then for k=1, 2, 3, ..., search for every possible substring of length k.

Because the suffix array is sorted, you can find a missing substring easily. For example, when k=2, you first find "aa", and then "ab" and so on.

Since a missing minimal substring is at most length O(log(n)), building the suffix array is O(n) and each scan is O(n), this is overall O(n log n).